# Rewrite json in loop

Tags: php, json

I have an array, which i wrote like a table for more reability.

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "title": "boune",
    "value": "3"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "title": "check",
    "value": "4"
}, {
    "id": "3",
    "title": "boune",
    "value": "5"
}]
```

As the result of what i want to see is this json, where 'value' of identical 'titles' united inside [] brackets. I am very newbie in php. I undestand that i need `for` loop to sort query result, but can`t heck...Cant even put my mind to it...

```
[{
    "id":"1",
    "title": "boune",
    "value": [3, 5]
}]
```

Comment: Can you instead show us the PHP array itself? Showing this in a tabular format is a bit ambiguous

Comment: @vivek_23 edited

Comment: Ok, but what would you do if title are same but ids' are different?

Comment: @vivek_23 If i have, for example two identical titles with ids 1 and 3, i want to choose 1.

Comment: Can you remove `sql` tags and add `json`, since this is more related to `json`?

Comment: Can you remove the SQL from your question title, too, since it's just misleading? There's also no for loop and I'm not sure if "Rearray" is a typo or something very special.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 

$json = '[{"id":"1","title":"boune","value":"3"},{"id":"2","title":"check","value":"4"},{"id":"3","title":"boune","value":"5"}]';

$json_data = json_decode($json,true);

function accumulateValuesByTitle($json_data){
    $hash = [];
    foreach($json_data as $each_record){
        if(isset($hash[$each_record['title']])){
            $hash[$each_record['title']]['value'][] = $each_record['value'];
            if($hash[$each_record['title']]['id'] > $each_record['id']){
                $hash[$each_record['title']]['id'] = $each_record['id'];
            }
        }else{
            $hash[$each_record['title']] = $each_record;
            $hash[$each_record['title']]['value'] = [$hash[$each_record['title']]['value']];
        }
    }

    return array_values($hash);
}


$modified_data = accumulateValuesByTitle($json_data);

echo json_encode($modified_data);
```